# Leading spaces in textarea from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string

I'm retrieving data from a mysql table column and placing it into a textarea.

When I do this, I get a huge section of leading spaces for only the first row of data.  I've tried using mysql TRIM and PHP TRIM functions, and neither of them seem to work.  Additionally, when I query the database directly, there are no leading spaces:

```
+-----------------+
| article_content |
+-----------------+
| # Test
        |
+-----------------+
```

Has anyone had this issue before?

[image]

Comment: Post your code. Probably you have an error somewhere.

Comment: What does the HTML source show? If not spaces, what is there?

Comment: Also wouldn't hurt to post the Column Schema for that Table / Column.

Comment: This always happens - I'll post my update ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens more often than not, but I try for several hours to fix something and can't figure it out, and then I post here on stack overflow, and then the answer hits me.

The issue was with my HTML section.  I forgot that textarea will interpret all spaces and tabs, etc, so when I indented my code that is inside some PHP code, it interpreted it, and inserted the spaces/tabs.